# Unable to connect to Cassandra after upgrade to 3.0.0

Tags: php, linux, cassandra, datastax-php-driver, cassandra-3.0

I've upgraded Cassandra to 3.0.0 some minutes ago through apt-get upgrade (on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS) and after installation and restarting I could connect to my keyspaces using the cqlsh tool and all was ok but when I tried to connect using the DataStax PHP Driver the first time I got "All connections on all I/O threads are busy" but now I get "No hosts available for the control connection". Connection data are the same, so 127.0.0.1 and the default port 9042, I didn't change nothing in configuration. I've tried to downgrade Cassandra to 2.2.3 but after installation it doesn't complete the start sequence. Is this a bug, of Cassandra or of PHP Driver? 
There are any ways to restore it without lost datas (with 3.0 or lower version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Version 3+ is not supported. Not even their enterprise version supports Cassandra 3+**: [Compatible versions of DataStax Enterprise and Cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibilityDocument.html)

The error messaging of the DataStax PHP Driver could use some improvement...

Things that got me before with this error message:

- Make sure you are connecting to the right server.
- Might be a conflict
  between the different versions.

But as far as I know, the DataStax PHP Driver does not support Cassandra 3+. Only version 2.1. And also version 2.2, but not completely.

From their docs:

> Compatibility
>   This driver works exclusively with the Cassandra Query
>   Language v3 (CQL3) and Cassandra’s native protocol. The current
>   version works with:
>
> Apache Cassandra versions 1.2, 2.0 and partially 2.1 DataStax
>   Enterprise 3.1, 3.2, 4.0 and 4.5 PHP 5.3.4+ Compilers: GCC 4.1.2+,
>   Clang 3.4+, and MSVC 2010/2012/2013 NOTE: Apache Cassandra 2.1 support
>   is limited to the Cassandra 2.0 API (native protocol v2), e.g. no
>   user-defined types.

[DataStax PHP Driver for Apache Cassandra](http://datastax.github.io/php-driver/#compatibility)

Unfortunately I don't know anything about downgrading Cassandra...

Comment: Thanks very much, as I seen it supports 2.1 version (partially), until now I used it also with 2.2.3, but it doesn't support useful data type like FROZEN and TUPLE, I hope that DataStax will release an update soon. About downgrade I read that it's not allowed from an upper version so I exported datas and reinstalled Cassandra 2.2.3